# How to use Moment js with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use a date picker in chrome extension with content.js file format to MM/DD/YY. I also try to import Momentjs into the project but I don't know how to import please help me thank you

```
window.onload = () => {

  const input = document.createElement('input');

  input.id = "scheduleTime"
  input.className = "input-text-date";
  input.setAttribute('type', 'date');
  input.setAttribute('data-date-format', 'MMMM DD YYYY');
  input.setAttribute('data-date', '');

  input.value = new Date().toLocaleDateString("sv") 

  document.querySelector(".game-scope").append(input);

}
```